# Set target in .csproj for gulp build

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild, gulp

We moved to visual studio and we are facing some problem with TFS and my gulp build process.

In TFS, We have dev and beta environment before prod. **Now my question is, after changing code in local how can I run gulp task (gulp dev) in .csproj  as a  so I can create main.css for dev and path change in my mainlayout.cshtml?**

For ex: I have updated event.scss in local and it will modify my local main.css(which is not in TFS and Project - so we will not get permission issues). Upon check-in from TFS I have to create main.css for dev so that it will render in dev environment. 
I know it's done by build manager, but "How?" That I don't know.

Please help me with this, if you can. :)

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 4):

You can run gulp by using Exec task, for example:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild"> 
     <!-- Is node installed? --> 
    <Exec  
       Command="node || start http://nodejs.org &amp;&amp; echo You need to install NodeJS" ContinueOnError="false" /> 
     <!-- it is, so have npm install all dependencies --> 
     <Exec  
       WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)"  
       Command="npm install"  
       ContinueOnError="false" /> 
     <!-- npm installed bower for us, so now let bower install it's dependencies --> 
     <Exec  
      WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)"  
       Command="node_modules\.bin\bower install"  
       ContinueOnError="false" /> 
     <!-- run the gulp task for the appropriate configuration --> 
     <Exec  
       WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)"  
       Command="node_modules\.bin\gulp $(Configuration)"  
       ContinueOnError="false" /> 
   </Target>
```

Check [this](https://gist.github.com/vanbilt/1c2694838114a2c852ae) article.